# Cannot make a python program to scan a number entered by the user and check if it a palindrome, Armstrong number and a perfect number

Tags: python

I want to scan a number and print that it a palindrome, Armstrong number or a perfect number in python, I tried it the following way but it doesn't work, I have checked them individually and they work as intended.
CODE:

```
#Palindrome
n=int(input("Enter number:"))
temp=n
rev=0
while(n>0):
    dig=n%10
    rev=rev*10+dig
    n=n//10
if(temp==rev):
    print(n,"The number is a palindrome!")
else:
    print(n,"The number isn't a palindrome!")
#Armstrong
sum = 0
temp = n
while temp > 0:
   digit = temp % 10
   sum += digit ** 3
   temp //= 10
if n == sum:
   print(n,"is an Armstrong number")
else:
   print(n,"is not an Armstrong number")
#Perfect Number
sum1 = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    if(n % i == 0):
        sum1 = sum1 + i
if (sum1 == n):
    print(n,"The number is a Perfect number!")
else:
    print(n,"The number is not a Perfect number!")
```

Comment: One problem is that after it checks for palindrome, n becomes 0 as you are dividing it by 10 as `n=n//10`.So n becomes 0 and as sum is 0, it prints all numbers as armstrong number

Comment: I suggest to use functions, so the environment is not dirty because of other calculations you make

Comment: You defined `temp` which is good, but then used `n` instead of it... Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The palindrome code modifies `n`, and then you directly re-use it for *amstrong* and *perfect*, you have to get back to the initial number, for that use your `temp`

```
#Armstrong
sum = 0
n = temp
```

Also do the following, for the same reason `n` has changed

```
print(temp, "The number is a palindrome!")
```

---

But the best way to get rid of that, and a bettre way to code, is to use methods

```
def palindrome(n):
    temp = n
    rev = 0
    while n > 0:
        dig = n % 10
        rev = rev * 10 + dig
        n = n // 10
    if temp == rev:
        print(temp, "The number is a palindrome!")
    else:
        print(temp, "The number isn't a palindrome!")

def armstrong(n):
    count = 0
    temp = n
    while temp > 0:
        digit = temp % 10
        count += digit ** 3
        temp //= 10
    if n == count:
        print(n, "is an Armstrong number")
    else:
        print(n, "is not an Armstrong number")

def perfect(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            count = count + i
    if count == n:
        print(n, "The number is a Perfect number!")
    else:
        print(n, "The number is not a Perfect number!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input("Enter number:"))
    palindrome(n)
    armstrong(n)
    perfect(n)
```